# Neo4j Cypher sorting and pattern comprehension

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE id(parentD) = 89592 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]->(sortValue89686:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(sortCharacteristic89686:Characteristic) 
WHERE id(sortCharacteristic89686) = 89686 
WITH ru, u, childD , sortValue89686 
ORDER BY sortValue89686.value ASC, childD.name DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100 
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) | {entityId: id(entity),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1:Criterion)<-[:VOTED_ON]-(vg1:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_FOR]->(childD) | {criterionId: id(c1),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[:SET_ON]-(v1:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(childD) | {characteristicId: id(ch1),  value: v1.value, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

Right now the following part in this query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]->(sortValue89686:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(sortCharacteristic89686:Characteristic) 
WHERE id(sortCharacteristic89686) = 89686
```

produces nulls for all pattern comprehension in the return statement. The `commentGroups`, `weightedCriteria` and `valuedCharacteristics` are not null and contain values only for records where `sortValue89686.value` is not null.

[image]

Instead of NULLs at the screenshot above I expect a values(for `commentGroups`, `weightedCriteria` and `valuedCharacteristics`) for rows even when `sortValue89686.value` is null.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: You've mentioned `sortValue212`, but I don't see that anywhere in the query. Can you clarify what this is?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Sorry, in this particular case this is `sortValue89686.value`.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be the result of a bug affecting Neo4j 3.1.1 and below (likely [this one](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/8606), or at least related to it).

I can reproduce your results with Neo4j 3.1.1, but not in Neo4j 3.1.2 (no nulls, results look good).

Try upgrading to 3.1.2 (it's not set as their default newest release, so grab it from [here](https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/)) and give it a spin.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Please ignore my previous comments. Everything works perfect with Windows Standalone Neo4j 3.1.2 and appropriate Embedded version. I'm also going to check it with my Linux stage env.